# Intellij: Restart a server with a shortcut?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm find it annoying and rather time consuming to switch to my server tab to restart it (tomcat) when I've made some changes.  Is there a shortcut to do this so I don't have to use my mouse?

My "run tomcat" configuration is almost *never* the one currently selected.  I usually have something else like an integration test or unit test selected.

Comment: Shift + F10 or Shift + F9 isn't that the short-cut?  Alternatively Cntrl + F10 for restart

Comment: Why do you actually restart tomcat? Wouldn't a re-deploy be sufficient?

Comment: @ChristianHujer that'd work too. Either way.